# How can we convert a String variable into JsonString in restAssured

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

question->
here I want to convert the qciResponse variable into Json and fetch userId from qciResponse, how can we do that..?

```
public String setRemoveLoginIdRequestBody (String awsEndPoint, String loginId) throws Exception {
    JSONObject joi = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject requestbody = new JSONObject();
    String qciResponse;
    if(loginId.contains("@")) {
        qciResponse = queryCombinedInfo(awsEndPoint,loginId,"email");
    } else {
       qciResponse = queryCombinedInfo(awsEndPoint,loginId,"mobile");
    }
    if (qciResponse==null || qciResponse.isEmpty()){
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

this is my code i want to convert qciResponse into json
here, qciResponse stores the response of queryCombinedInfo method
i am writing code like this but this is giving error

```
String h = qciResponse.toJSONString;
```

Comment: I might be missing the point, why don't you get userId from one of the above mentioned JSONObjects? Why do you have to get it from qciResponse, which currently is a String?

Comment: qciResponse stores the response of queryCombinedInfo method 
and i want userId which coming in response of queryCombinedInfo method

Comment: @DeepaliSinha there is nothing called `JSONString` in rest-assured. It's just String. Instead of converting from `Response` to `String` then get value, you can get value directly from `Response`.